# How to initialise keyup function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //window.onload = LabourPrice;

    //Control Proofing Time and LabourCost
    $('#ArtworkDetail_NoOfProofs').keyup(function () {
        function LabourPrice() {
            var time = "@Model.ArtworkDetail.ProofType.DefaultProofTime".split(':');
            var seconds = (+time[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+time[1]) * 60 + (+time[2]);
            var newSeconds = seconds * $('#ArtworkDetail_NoOfProofs').val();

            var date = new Date(newSeconds * 1000);
            var hh = date.getUTCHours();
            var mm = date.getUTCMinutes();
            var ss = date.getSeconds();

            var hourlyLabour = $('#LabourCostCentrePrice').val();
            hourlyLabour = hourlyLabour.split('£');
            var costPerSecond = hourlyLabour[1] / 3600;
            var calculateCost = costPerSecond * newSeconds;
            //alert("£"+calculateCost.toFixed(2));
            $('#ArtworkDetail_ProofingLabourCost').val("£" + calculateCost.toFixed(2));

            // If building a timestamp instead of a duration, you would uncomment the following line to get 12-hour (not 24) time
            if (hh > 12) { hh = hh % 12; }
            // Ensure each element has two-digits
            if (hh < 10) { hh = "0" + hh; }
            if (mm < 10) { mm = "0" + mm; }
            if (ss < 10) { ss = "0" + ss; }
            // Format your to HH:MM:SS
            var t = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
            $('#ArtworkDetail_ProofType_DefaultProofTime').val(t);
        }
        });

});
```

I would like to call the keyup function on page load in order to run some default value I have within a calculation, as the price initially starts off as empty.

Could I do something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   window.onload = LabourPrice;
    ....
  }
```

Then how would I wrap LabourPrice?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Added Function Detail as requested

Comment: can you tell us what is inside of keyup?

Comment: You can just trigger the event with `.trigger('keyup')`, but if it will work depends on what the event handler does ?

Comment: @adeneo Please look again

Comment: @DarkShadowAY I am little bit confuse it is working. function within function.

Comment: Write 2 separate events/functions LabourPrice and keyup event inside $(document).ready().. And not the nested one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `window.onload` is redundant as that is part of `ready` and the event needs to be set inside the `ready` function. Why not try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ArtworkDetail_NoOfProofs').keyup(function () {
    });
    LabourPrice();
}
function LabourPrice() {
}
```

Assuming that `LabourPrice` is a function (just seen your edit). This function definition can go outside the `ready`

Answer (score 2):

`LabourPrice` should be outside of the `keyup` event. As you have it now, `LabourPrice` only exists within the keyup event, but you want to call it from the keyup event:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#ArtworkDetail_NoOfProofs').keyup(function () {
    LabourPrice();
  }
}

function LabourPrice(){ ... }
```

[Here's a good source](https://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/) on how window.load is different than document.ready, although this is not your main issue.